# Slick and Youtube video pause on play start on end video

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I'm using slick.js to show a Youtube video in the carousel. That video should autoplay when slide is visible and after end of the video the next slide need to be shown.

I have found a great [codepen](https://codepen.io/digistate/pen/MvapbE) idea which exactly does what I want. However I just can't figure out how to stop the autoplay of the slider when the youtube video plays and at the end continue to next slide.

What I have is this (those weird tags are Twig tags):

```
<section id="headlines" class="main-slider banner">
   <div class="slide-item youtube">
     <iframe class="embed-player slide-media" width="980" height="520" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ theme.video_url }}?enablejsapi=1&controls=1&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&rel=0&showinfo=0&loop=1&playlist={{ theme.video_url }}&start={{ theme.video_start_time }}&end={{ theme.video_end_time }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</section>

<script>
 var slideWrapper = $(".main-slider"),
    iframes = slideWrapper.find('.embed-player'),
    lazyImages = slideWrapper.find('.slide-image'),
    lazyCounter = 0;

// POST commands to YouTube or Vimeo API
function postMessageToPlayer(player, command){
  if (player == null || command == null) return;
  player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), "*");
  //console.log(command, player)
}

// When the slide is changing
function playPauseVideo(slick, control){
  var currentSlide, slideType, startTime, player, video;
  currentSlide = slick.find(".slick-current");
  slideType = currentSlide.attr("class").split(" ")[1];
  player = currentSlide.find("iframe").get(0);
  startTime = currentSlide.data("video-start");

  if (slideType === "youtube") {
    switch (control) {
      case "play":
        postMessageToPlayer(player, {
          "event": "command",
          "func": "mute"
        });
        postMessageToPlayer(player, {
          "event": "command",
          "func": "playVideo"
        });
        break;
      case "pause":
        postMessageToPlayer(player, {
          "event": "command",
          "func": "pauseVideo"
        });
        break;
    }
  }
}
$(function() {

  // Initialize
  slideWrapper.on("init", function(slick){
    slick = $(slick.currentTarget);
    setTimeout(function(){
      playPauseVideo(slick,"play");
    }, 1000);
  });
  slideWrapper.on("beforeChange", function(event, slick) {
    slick = $(slick.$slider);
    playPauseVideo(slick, "pause");
  });
  slideWrapper.on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    slick = $(slick.$slider);
    playPauseVideo(slick, "play");
   
    /* THIS IS WHAT I TRIED */ 
    /* var vid = $(slick[currentSlide]).find('video');
    if (vid.length > 0) {
      slideWrapper.slick('slickPause');
      $(vid).get(0).play();
    }    
    $('video').on('ended',function(){           
      console.log('Video Complete')
      slideWrapper.slick('slickPlay');
    });*/

  });


  //start the slider
  slideWrapper.slick({
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed:4000,
      lazyLoad:"progressive",
      speed:600,
      arrows:true,
      dots:true,
      cssEase:"cubic-bezier(0.87, 0.03, 0.41, 0.9)"
    });
  });

</script>
```

I just can't see how I can still set the carousel to autoplay but stop the autoplay at a video, and resume autoplay after the video ends. Or do I have the wrong approach?

Comment: The are 2 options: the easiest is hard coded. Since you know what's the duration of the videos you can pause the slider to the current slider duration video and continue after that time. The harder is to use [youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) and/or [vimeo](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/basics) apis to listen to the video state changes and act as response.

Comment: @Mosh Feu: Listen to the YT api I understand. But how would you do this with hardcoded end times? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

By refering to the [youtube api reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), You can listen to the event `onStateChange`

Here is the list of status this events returns:

- -1 (unstarted)
- 0 (ended)
- 1 (playing)
- 2 (paused)
- 3 (buffering)
- 5 (video cued).

In code, it looks like this

```js
//We create a variable which will contain our youtube `Player` object
var player;

//This function is a YT event that wait the API is ready
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        //the `events` parameters lets us chose the different event we want to look after
        player = new YT.Player( 'player', {
          events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
        });
}


//Now our event is setup, we can design the function that will be fired each time the event is trigger by our YT object
function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
  if(e.data = 0) {
    // THE EVENT.DATA IS EQUAL TO 0
    // YOUR VIDEO COMES TO AN END, INSERT HERE YOUR CODE TO GO TO 
    // THE NEXT SLIDER FOR EXAMPLE
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- don't forget the id player, the youtube api ready event needs it to target your video as 1rst parameter -->
<iframe width='200' height='200' id='player'src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tpiyEe_CqB4?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean! I don't have problems to start the video but to slide to next slide when video ends. Can you perhaps make an example of what you mean?

Comment: @Meules here you go

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It's not what I was after. I was looking for an answer which works in Slick slider. Your pprovided code I was aware of but I could just not get it to work with slick. It goes to next slide during the video or it does not go to next slide after the video. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: oh, ok. Sorry it was not the answer you were seeking.